# How to sparse a string date which is aggregate by hour in a date format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm currently working on a special string date format which is aggregate by hour, here is an example:

```
date
0   2019-03-05-19
1   2019-03-05-19
2   2019-03-05-19
3   2019-03-05-19
4   2019-03-08-17
```

For example, for any hour n between **1AM** and **2PM (1:00, 1:10, 1:15, ...)** his time value will be transform in the number 19 at the end of the string, between **2AM** and **3PM** the values will be 17, ...

I would like to conserve this special format for my study, but, I'm looking for how to change the string format in a recognize date format which could understand the particularity of my string date.
Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear as you say "any hour n between 1AM and 2PM", but here is my solution:

```
>>> d = {'19': ' 01:00', '17': ' 14:00'}
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.rsplit('-', 1).apply(lambda x: x[0] + d[x[1]]))
0   2019-03-05 01:00:00
1   2019-03-05 01:00:00
2   2019-03-05 01:00:00
3   2019-03-05 01:00:00
4   2019-03-08 14:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry about my unclear explanations, I edited my question. I just mean for exemple if we have hours like 1:00,  1:10, 1:30,  ... (so. between 1AM until 2AM) for each entry of this time slot, the time is replace by one number at the end of my. date string.  It is useful for my study because I need to aggregate entries (again for exemple) between 1AM and 2AM.  So I would like to conserve the format of my date but I just would like to change the type of my date, for the moment it is considered as a string but I need that it be considered as date .

Comment: @JEG Where are the actual times, i can't *guess* it

Comment: There is no actual time, I just work with past time series, I posted at the top the their format